# Get files of user defined sizes C#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to find a way to display files that are within 1MB of user defined file size. so far I have tried this but it comes up as invalid

```
DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows");
FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();

Console.WriteLine("Enter a file size in Bytes i.e 500 bytes");
int userSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
FileInfo[] files = files.GetLegnth(userSize);
```

I am a beginner at this and I dont understand How I am supposed to get files within 1MB of user specified sizwe.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Really a very basic math and algorithm. Sounds like a school assignment more than a serious programming problem. Consult this with your teacher instead, we're not here to teach basics like this.

Comment: @walther People come here to get help and guidance in programming, if you can't do that then don't submit useless comments on others' posts please

Comment: You'd get your answer if you've read through first few chapters in your book or in any programming tutorial. Really, how hard is to compare against two bounds? It's a basic logic that's being taught in primary schools. Hate me how hard you want, it won't change a thing.

Comment: @walther look, if you don't want to help, fine dont. But dont go around expecting people to have the same level of understanding as you. As I said, I am a beginner, seeing things as a programming language is hard enough for me without users like you making it worse.

Comment: @Farha problem is, SO is not really a place to learn programming as a beginner. It is a place to **help** solve specific programming questions and problems. Hence, when people with little to none knowledge of what they are asking come here for help, they're seen more like people who just want someone else to solve their problem rather than people who want to solve a problem. Basics can be learnt from a lot of other sources (books, tutorials, etc) and I encourage you to first try to understand what the problem is rather than just asking for a solution "because you're a beginner"

Comment: @JoshPart I was actually looking for guidance, not solutions. I tried a Book, i actually have a stack of C# based books, may be I just don't understand it enough. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Farha don't worry. We all started from the very beginning. Perhaps the urge made you look directly for a solution of the general problem. My advice is, when you encouter yoursel with something you can't seem to solve, split it into smaller problems and try to solve them one by one. E.g. in this case you could have looked first how to get information of all files of a directory, then how to get their filesize, then how to check from a group of values wich are inside a range, etc... take away the "I don't understand because I'm a beginner" from your mind, that doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't provide a code in this answer, because it's really basic and you should be the one who finds the final solution. If you need to get files of size within some set bounds (+- 1MB for instance), you first need to get all the files and `loop` through them to find their sizes. In the loop you'd be checking if it's within these bounds or not. If it is, you can assign the file/size/whatever, into an array of found stuff. If not, simply go to the next file.

I'd really **AVOID** linq solutions, because you need to learn and understand the principles first and then use shortcuts. Otherwise you'd be dependent on SO help for a looooong time.

I'll just show you how you get the bounds, rest is up to you:

```
Console.Write("Type the desired size in bytes: ");
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
int userSize = int.Parse(userInput); // you might consider using TryParse here

int upperBound = userSize + 1048576;
int lowerBound = userSize - 1048576;

// get the files of a directory you want to search

// loop through and compare their size
// if their size is > or = to the lower bound 
//              AND < or = to the upper bound, 
//          you've found match and add it to results
```

*Just a note: 1048576 bytes = 1 megabyte*
*Second note: you should probably check if the lower bound is higher or equal to zero, if the user typed in a valid number and so on...*

Comment: Thank you, as for Looping, yes I have looped through the files now I suppose I just need comparisons using if statements

Comment: Thank you once again, I will be using boolean to determine if user input is valid or not.

Comment: @Farha, you're welcome... Btw, I didn't mean to be offensive, it's just the amount of people who come here and ask for a final solution without even trying, that gets me mad. Sorry. Josh Part pretty much nailed the point I was trying to make.

Comment: Don't worry about it, I don't really have to do this part its just for bonus points. I understand people coming here for final solutions, I only come here after I have tried what I can and ask for guidance not exactly solutions. I didn't mean to be offensive either, so if you found it offensive, I apologize. Thank You though, for your help

Comment: Thank you, I worked out the rest, it took a while because I find this very confusing but here is the full code, the code to get the files and the directory info codes were already declared

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [IEnumerable extension Where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) applied to your files array

First you need to define the upper and lower limit of your allowed file sizes, then ask the Where extension to examine your files collection to extract the files that are between your limits

```
int upperLimit = (1024 * 1024) + userSize;
int lowerLimit = Math.Max(0, usersize - (1024 * 1024));
var result = files.Where(x => x.Length >= lowerLimit && x.Length  <= upperLimit);
foreach(FileInfo fi in result)
   Console.WriteLIne(fi.Name + " size = " + fi.Length);
```

Comment: You need to add: `using System.Linq;`

Comment: For your solution above?

Comment: Yes, it is not clear what do you mean with _within 1MB of user specified size_ As above you will get back all the files with a size less than the user input value.

Comment: I mean that when user selects an option, they will be asked to enter a size and then I have to display all files that are 1MB smaller or larger than what the user specified

Comment: Update with a more precise answer for upper and lower limits

Answer (score 0):

```
 FileInfo[] files = files.GetLegnth(userSize);
```

this is called wishful programming. Just hoping that the system will have a function that does exactly what you need.

What you need to do in go through the files collection and look at each length in turn. SOmething like

```
var matched = files.Where(f=>f.Size > userSize);
```

if you like LINQ or

```
foreach(var file in files)
{
   if (file.Size>userSize)
  {
  }
}
```

if you dont

note - I doubt this code works as typed, I have not read up on the data in a File object, there must be a Size of some sort

Comment: yes there is a size of some sort, I will try this too and see which is the one I best understand

Comment: FileInfo class has the property Length for _the size, in bytes, of the current file_

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, please confirm, if this what you need

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DirectoryInfo folderInfo = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Windows");
            FileInfo[] files = folderInfo.GetFiles();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter a file size in Bytes i.e 500 bytes");
            int userSize = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            FileInfo[] totalFiles = files.Where(x => x.Length == userSize).ToArray();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It says system.IO does not contain a definition for where

Comment: please Add namesapce System.Linq;

Comment: I did add System.Linq

Comment: Okay Thanks, as @walther said, using Linq is hard for a beginner like myself to understand. But Thank you anyway